# How to create multi editable cells on click in React-table

Tags: reactjs

I have a table with 4 columns: First Name, Last Name, City, Address. If the user click on City, City and Address becomes editable.

```
class Home extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {

            columns : [
                {
                    Header: 'First Name',
                    accessor: 'firstName'
                },
                {
                    Header: 'Last Name',
                    accessor: 'lastName'
                },

                {
                    Header: 'City',
                    accessor: 'city',
                    Cell: this.clickableCell
                },
                {
                    Header: 'Address',
                    accessor: 'addr'
                }

            ],

            data: [ 
                {
                    firstName: "MyName",
                    lastName: "MyLastName",
                    city: "MyCity",
                    addr: "My Address"
                }
           ],

        };

    }

    renderEditable = (cellInfo) => {

        const products = this.state.data;
        const row = products[cellInfo.index];
        const value = row[cellInfo.column.id]

        return (
            <div contentEditable suppressContentEditableWarning>
                {value}
            </div>
        )
    };

    clickableCell = (cellInfo) => {

        const products = this.state.data;
        const row = products[cellInfo.index];
        const value = row[cellInfo.column.id]

        const onClick = () => {
            let c = Object.assign({}, this.state);

            // Change the City and Address Cell's function to create an 
            // editable cell
            c.columns[2]['Cell'] = this.renderEditable;
            c.columns[3]['Cell'] = this.renderEditable;

            this.setState({...c});
            this.forceUpdate();
        }

        return (
            <div onClick={onClick}>
                {value}
            </div>
        )
    };
    render() {
        return(
            <ReactTable
                className="-striped -highlight"
                data={this.state.data}
                columns={this.state.columns} 
            />
        )
    }
}
```

My idea was bind to City's Cell a function to create a clickable div and after replace the Cell's function with a different function to render an editable div..but this idea doesn't work...

Comment: first of all: in clickableCell you need to change `this.data` to `this.state.data`.  `this` refers to the instance of `class Home` here.

Comment: I fixed, but the issue remains